# Working with four-vectors (4-vectors)

Tags: vector, physics

Given an expression

$\chi\,=\,C_{p1}\,\left[ h\,e^{- i\,p1.\,x}\,\, +\,\,h^{\dagger}\,e^{+i\,p1\,.\,x}\right]$

where $p1$ and $x$ are four-vectors; $C_{p1} = \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2 \pi)^3} \sqrt{2 \omega\,(p1,\ m)}}$, and $x\ .\ p1\ =\omega(p_1,m)\,t\ - {\vec p1} {\vec x}$

Please note that "$x$" and "$\chi$" are different variables. $x$ is a 4-vector, the components of which are $t$, and the three components of $\vec {x}$. Similarly, $p1$ is a 4-vector with components $\omega(p_1,m)$ and the three components of $\vec p1$.

How does one teach Mathematica to do things like gradient of $\chi $, $\partial_{t} \chi$, product of $\chi$ i.e. $\chi^2$ etc. but not have to explicitly have to type the full form of the four vectors - in the subsequent input and results of evaluations?

For the product of $\chi$s, it would be great if the variables could be programmed such that the first $\chi$ would take $p1$ and $x1$ as arguments, the second $\chi$ - $p2$ and $x2$ etc.

Comment: `Dot`, `D`....?

Comment: $\chi\ . \chi$ - meant to express $\chi^2$, where the first instance of $\chi$ would contain $p1$ as the 4-vector (i.e. $\omega(p1, m$, $\vec p1$ etc.), the second instance of $\chi$ would have $p2$ as the 4-vector etc.

Comment: You would have to teach us how to do these things before we can give you any advice on how to implement it.

Comment: Well, $p1\cdot\chi$ would be `p1.chi`, short for `Dot[p1, chi]`, as explained in the docs. `D` computes partial derivatives and gradients. If you have trouble implementing these in your code, I think we'll need to see the code to give help.

Comment: It's not $p1 . \chi$, $x$ and $\chi$ are different variables.

Comment: In general if you are going to do tensor calculations, I recommend the free and powerful xact package. (www.xact.es)

Comment: One method is of course to explicitly substitute for $p1$.$x$ $\to t \omega \left(\text{p1}_x,m\right)$ - $ \vec{x}$ * $\vec{p1}$ in the original expression, but then the 4-vectors are no longer succinct, and calculations later get unwieldy because it may be required to reverse the expression back to the original 4-vector form.

Comment: After 2+ hours of editing the question, it's still showing up as "on hold". If meta-users can't understand the question, it doesn't necessarily mean that it's intractable by other non-meta users. Perhaps this comment means that my membership will be suspended?

Comment: @MichaelE2 The key point appears to be that suman_b wants the metric to have signature (1,-1,-1,-1) rather than the usual metric (1,1,1,1).  So `Dot` won't be quite enough.  I second using `xact`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Finally, someone who responds with some clarity to my first inquiry. The xAct comment helped a lot. Thanks. The problem (for me) is that are all these symbols, sometimes used with minor variations, which apparently have a standard meaning in some field but not mine. People should realize they're on a programming site, not a physics site (or whatever), and write their questions appropriately. The OP now has $\vec{p}1$, $p1$ and $p_1$, as well as a $\vec{p1}$ in a comment, and I cannot tell the difference, if any, between the four symbols.

Comment: $p1$ has been used in the original question, there is no p_subscript_1. 
$\vec{p1}$ typeset sometimes renders the vector sign only over the $p$, the rendered fonts are rather inconsistent.  In summary $p$ is a 4-vector, so is $p1$. $\vec{p}$ is a 3-vector, and so is $\vec{p1}$.

Comment: But I copied the TeX ...`p1\ =\omega(p_1,m)\,t`... from your question.  There's also a $p1_x$ in a comment. I'm not sure if that's a derivative or a component or a typo. Is $\vec{p1}$ related to $p1$ -- it's not just any 3-tuple, but three particular components of the 4-tuple $p1$, yes? Which three? Or do I have that wrong? -- Well, I don't think you really need to respond. It's going to be too much effort for me to figure out how to help, especially if xAct turns out to be what you need. But maybe look at the Q again fix any typos like `p_1`.

Comment: There's a typo in one of the comments, but not in the original question (as far as I can see). A position four vector $x$ is explicitly written as (t, $\vec{x}$). A momentum four vector $p$ is explicitly written as $(\omega, \vec{p})$, where $\omega$ is a function of $\vec{p}$ and $m$ (as in the original question).

Comment: @suman_b Please kindly read this network-wide FAQ: [**What is a “closed” or “on hold” question?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question)

Comment: Cross-posted: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/995827

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will get you started?

```
χ[t_, x_] = cp1 (h Exp[-I (t ω + x p)] + hDag Exp[I (t ω + x p)])
```

Then

```
D[χ[t,x], t]
(*   cp1 (-I E^(-I (p x + t ω)) h ω + I E^(I (p x + t ω)) hDag ω)   *)
```

and

```
D[χ[t,x], t]
(*   cp1 (-I E^(-I (p x + t ω)) h p + I E^(I (p x + t ω)) hDag p)  *)
```

Comment: Thank you QuantumDot, yes this works. 

Is there a way to state that x consists of 4 components that behave or transform like a vector? I understand that there are packages out there like xact, but without such a package.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no quick way to achieve what you want.  You'll need to write some code to get it done.  For example, you can use `Indexed[x,μ]` to represent a generic four-vector `x` with index `μ`.  Then you'll need to define your own differentiation $\partial x_\mu/\partial x_\nu = \delta_{\mu\nu}$ like this `MyGradient[Indexed[x_,mu_],Indexed[x_,nu_]] := Indexed[δ,{mu,nu}]`.  A lot more work is needed because you'll have to also include standard rules of differentiation, and define how $\delta_{\mu\nu}$ works.  Then you'll want to define dot product, and differentiation rules...

Comment: @suman_b see my comment above.  Also, what exactly do you want to achieve.  What sort of calculations do you ultimately want to do?

Comment: Thanks QuantumDot. Yes, I need to do the calculations / program similar to the ones you stated. I tried using FeynCalc package, but the following didn't work out:

p1 :=FourVector[ $\omega$[p1,m], m] 
x := FourVector[t,r],  
Chi: = Integrate[C[p1] (h[p1] e$^{-I p1 x}$ + h$^{\dagger}$[p1] E$^{I p1 x}$, d$\vec{p1}$ 


p1 = ( $\omega$[p1, m]*t, $\vec{p1}$) and x = (t, $\vec{x}$).

Comment: @suman_b Recall that `Integrate` is a top-level built-in *Mathematica* package, so you cannot expect any 3rd party packages to teach it how to work with objects native to that package (like `FourVector`).  You'll need to write your own rules for that.  Couple questions: are you fairly new to *Mathematica*? Are you also somewhat new to physics?  My suggestion is for you to do these calculations by hand, unless you're doing a heavy-duty research-level project that necessitates computer algebra.

Comment: Thank you QuantumDot. Yes, very new to Mathematica. Not new to Physics, but not an expert in field theory either. You are absolutely right, have done quite a few such calculations by hand. Now tired of having to revisit mistakes, because it is a somewhat heavy-duty manipulation that's to be performed, and automating in Mathematica makes it repeatable. Is there a way to contact you?